# to convert php report page to PDF format

Tags: php, pdf

I am new to php and dont know how to convert php file to pdf.

I am trying to convert this following code to pdf, but i was not successful.

Kindly help me in converting this, its a kind of urgent.I have also attached an image for which i wants the conversion.

```
<?
$Section = isset($_GET['Section'])?$_GET['Section']:"";
?>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <div id="loginpanel" >
    <h3>Performa regarding Contempt Petition ('A'Category) Cases Report</h3>
  </div> 
<br />
<p id="demo" align="right" style="font-size:12px"></p>

<a href="<?=DIR_WS_SITE_CONTROL?>index.php?Page=pdf"          target="_blank">Download PDF</a>

<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>

<tr><td><br/></td></tr>
</table>

<?
  //// Section start
switch($Section)
{
   case "district_report":
   default:


 $ZoneObj = new DataTable(TABLE_ZONE);
 $ZoneObj->Where = "1";
 $ZoneObj->TableSelectAll();

 ?>

<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="TableBorder"    style="color:black">

   <tr class="InsideLeftTd">
      <td width="2%" height="25"><b>S.No</b></td>
      <td width="10%" align="left"><b>Circle</b></td>
      <td width="10%" align="left"><b>District</b></td>
      <td width="8%" align="left"><b>Total no of cases</b></td>
      <td width="8%" align="left"><b>Total no. of cases where reply filed</b></td>
      <td width="8%" align="left"><b>No. of cases due for hearing in next 21 days</b></td>
      <td width="8%" align="left"><b>No. of cases due for hearing in next 21 days(Reply Filed)</b></td>
      <td width="8%" align="left"><b>No. of cases due for hearing in next 21 days(Reply Not Filed)</b></td>
  </tr>
 <?

 $SNo=1;
 $Count=1;
 while($CurrentZon=$ZoneObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
 {
   $circleObj = new DataTable(TABLE_CIRCLE);
   $circleObj->Where = "zone_id='".$CurrentZon->id."'";
   $circleObj->TableSelectAll();

 ?>
<tr>
  <td colspan="11" align="center"><b><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentZon->zone);?> Zone</b></td>
</tr>


<?  while($CurrentCir=$circleObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
 {  

   $DistrictObj = new DataTable(TABLE_DISTRICT);
   $DistrictObj->Where = "circle_id='".$CurrentCir->id."'";
   $DistrictObj->TableSelectAll();

 ?>

 <tr class="InsideRightTd">

    <td height="25" align="center" style="color:black" rowspan="<?=$DistrictObj->GetNumRows()?>"><?=$SNo?>.</td>

    <td align="left" style="color:black" rowspan="<?=$DistrictObj->GetNumRows()?>">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentCir->circle);?>
    </td>

  <?    while($CurrentDis=$DistrictObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
  {

   $ConObj = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."'";
   $Case_count=$ConObj->TableCountDistinct("id","id_count");

   $ConObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj2->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND reply_filed='Yes'";
   $Reply_count=$ConObj2->TableCountDistinct("id","reply_count");

   $ContObj = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ContObj->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."'";
   $ContObj->TableSelectAll();

   $ConObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj3->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."' AND reply_filed='Yes'";
   $ConObj3->TableSelectAll();

   $ConObj4 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj4->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."' AND reply_filed='No'";
   $Filed_count=$ConObj4->TableCountDistinct("id","next_count");

   ?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentDis->district);?></td>
    <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($Case_count->id_count);?></td>

   <?   if($Reply_count->reply_count!='0'){
        $color= (($Reply_count->reply_count)*100)/$Case_count->id_count;
    }else{
        $color = '0';
    }

    if($color=='0'){?>
      <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?>
      </td>

    <?}elseif($color<=65 & $color>0){?>

    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F75D59">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?>
    </td>

    <? }elseif($color>65 && $color<=90){?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?>
    </td>

    <? }elseif($color>90){?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?>
    </td>           
    <?}?>

    <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($ContObj->GetNumRows())?>
    </td>

    <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($ConObj3->GetNumRows())?>
    </td>


     <? if($Filed_count->next_count==0){?>

      <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Filed_count->next_count)?>
       </td>
      <?}else{?>
       <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F75D59">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Filed_count->next_count)?>
        </td>
        <?}?>

     </tr>


     <? 
   } 
    $SNo++;
    $Count++;

   ////////Circle Total Starts here////////////////////////////

   $ConObj5 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj5->Where = "circle_id='".$CurrentCir->id."'";
   $Case_count=$ConObj5->TableCountDistinct("id","id_count");

   $ConObj6 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj6->Where = "circle_id='".$CurrentCir->id."' AND reply_filed='Yes'";
   $Reply_count=$ConObj6->TableCountDistinct("id","reply_count");

   $ContObj7 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ContObj7->Where = "circle_id='".$CurrentCir->id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."'";
   $Hear_count=$ContObj7->TableCountDistinct("id","file_count");

   $ConObj7 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj7->Where = "circle_id='".$CurrentCir->id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."' AND reply_filed='Yes'";
   $Hearing_count=$ConObj7->TableCountDistinct("id","case_count");

   $ConObj8 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj8->Where = "circle_id='".$CurrentCir->id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."' AND reply_filed='No'";
   $Filed_count=$ConObj8->TableCountDistinct("id","next_count");       

   ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center"><b><?=$CurrentCir->circle?> Circle Total</b></td>
    <td align="center" style="color:black"><b><?=MyStripSlashes($Case_count->id_count);?></b></td>

     <? if($Reply_count->reply_count!='0'){
        $color= (($Reply_count->reply_count)*100)/$Case_count->id_count;
      }else{
        $color = '0';
       }

       if($color=='0'){?>
      <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?>
      </td>

    <?}elseif($color<=65 & $color>0){?>

      <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F75D59">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
      </td>

    <? }elseif($color>65 && $color<=90){?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
    </td>

    <? }elseif($color>90){?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
    </td>           
    <?}?>

    <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Hear_count->file_count)?></b>
    </td>

    <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Hearing_count->case_count)?></b>
    </td>

    <?  if($Filed_count->next_count==0){?>

    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Filed_count->next_count)?></b>
    </td>
    <?}else{?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F75D59">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Filed_count->next_count)?></b>
    </td>
    <?}?>

   </tr>

   <?
   /////////Zone total starts here/////////////////////////

   $ConObj5 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj5->Where = "zone_id='".$CurrentCir->zone_id."'";
   $Case_count=$ConObj5->TableCountDistinct("id","id_count");

   $ConObj6 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj6->Where = "zone_id='".$CurrentCir->zone_id."' AND reply_filed='Yes'";
   $Reply_count=$ConObj6->TableCountDistinct("id","reply_count");

   $ContObj7 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ContObj7->Where = "zone_id='".$CurrentCir->zone_id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."'";
   $Hear_count=$ContObj7->TableCountDistinct("id","fil_count");

   $ConObj7 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj7->Where = "zone_id='".$CurrentCir->zone_id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."' AND reply_filed='Yes'";
   $Hearing_count=$ConObj7->TableCountDistinct("id","case_count");

   $ConObj8 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj8->Where = "zone_id='".$CurrentCir->zone_id."' AND date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."' AND reply_filed='No'";
   $Filed_count=$ConObj8->TableCountDistinct("id","next_count");    



    } ?>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"><b><?=$CurrentZon->zone?> Zone Total</b>      </td>

    <td align="center" style="color:black"><b><?=MyStripSlashes($Case_count->id_count);?></b></td>

  <?    if($Reply_count->reply_count!='0'){
        $color= (($Reply_count->reply_count)*100)/$Case_count->id_count;
      }else{
        $color = '0';
      }

     if($color=='0'){?>
      <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?>
      </td>

      <?}elseif($color<=65 & $color>0){?>

      <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F75D59">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
      </td>

      <? }elseif($color>65 && $color<=90){?>
      <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
      </td>

      <? }elseif($color>90){?>
       <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
       </td>            
       <?}?>

        <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Hear_count->fil_count)?></b>
        </td>

        <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Hearing_count->case_count)?></b>
    </td>

   <?   if($Filed_count->next_count==0){?>

    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Filed_count->next_count)?></b>
    </td>
    <?}else{?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F75D59">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Filed_count->next_count)?></b>
    </td>
    <?}?>

    </tr>


   <?}

   /////////District total starts here//////////////////////////

   $ConObj5 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj5->Where = "1";
   $Case_count=$ConObj5->TableCountDistinct("id","id_count");

   $ConObj6 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj6->Where = "reply_filed='Yes'";
   $Reply_count=$ConObj6->TableCountDistinct("id","reply_count");

   $ContObj7 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ContObj7->Where = "date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."'";
   $Hear_count=$ContObj7->TableCountDistinct("id","file_count");

   $ConObj7 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj7->Where = "date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."' AND reply_filed='Yes'";
   $Hearing_count=$ConObj7->TableCountDistinct("id","case_count");

   $ConObj8 = new DataTable(TABLE_CONTEMPT_PETITION_A);
   $ConObj8->Where = "date_next_hearing>='".date('Y-m-d')."'  AND date_next_hearing <='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+21 days"))."' AND reply_filed='No'";
   $Filed_count=$ConObj8->TableCountDistinct("id","next_count");    

   ?>    
    <tr class="InsideRightTd">
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F5F5DC" colspan="3"><b> Grand Total</b></td>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F5F5DC"><b><?=MyStripSlashes($Case_count->id_count);?></b></td>

    <?  if($Reply_count->reply_count!='0'){
        $color= (($Reply_count->reply_count)*100)/$Case_count->id_count;
    }else{
        $color = '0';
    }

    if($color=='0'){?>
      <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?>
      </td>

    <?}elseif($color<=65 & $color>0){?>

      <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F75D59">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
      </td>

    <? }elseif($color>65 && $color<=90){?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
    </td>

    <? }elseif($color>90){?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Reply_count->reply_count)?></b>
    </td>           
    <?}?>

    <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Hear_count->file_count)?></b>
    </td>

    <td align="center" style="color:black">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Hearing_count->case_count)?></b>
    </td>

    <?  if($Filed_count->next_count==0){?>

    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Filed_count->next_count)?></b>
    </td>
    <?}else{?>
    <td align="center" style="color:black" bgcolor="#F75D59">
        <b><?=MyStripSlashes($Filed_count->next_count)?></b>
    </td>
    <?}?>
    </tr>

   </table>

  <?    break;
   }
  ?>

   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="color:black" align="center">
     <tr></tr><br/>

     <tr>
      <td>Less than 65% &nbsp;&nbsp;<div style="width:60px;height:20px;border:1px solid #000;background:#F75D59;"></div>     </td>
      <td>Between 65-90%&nbsp;&nbsp;<div style="width:60px;height:20px;border:1px solid #000;background:#FFFF00;"></div></td>
      <td>Greater Than 90% &nbsp;&nbsp;<div style="width:60px;height:20px;border:1px solid #000;background:#00FF00;"></div></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

This is a report and i want its pdf to be downloaded.

I am attaching its image also[image: report image for which i want pdf file]

Comment: Take a look at the [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) command line tool. It allows to render html to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a free windows soft called DoPdf. It's like a virtual printer you install on your PC, very light, easy, fast and painless. Install this "printer" on your PC and then, on your browser, "print" the page on that printer. All you will get is your nice and clean HTML converted to a PDF file saved on the folder you choose. You would even can configure resolution of the generated PDF, if it will be Portrait or Landscape, black n white or colored, so, it's a very popular and nice option. Plus every soft on your PC will be able to use this pdf creator too, anytime, for example, your OpenOffice, etc. Best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the thing is "this report needs to be downloaded from different locations with differemt computers not from mine only"

Comment: Then you will need to rely on a server side resourse, like the one (I think)  Alexander Popov said to you before me. Don't be afraid, it's not that hard thing to implement. 1) contact your ISP (where your site is hosted); 2) Ask'em if they have server side components that address this kind of demand - create a PDF "onfly" - and if your account afford the use of that technology; 3) Ask'em about code samples to implement on your pages; 4) it's time to code: with all your knowledge put a "Download as PDF" on your page, for users to click and manage the behind scenes. I'm sure you'll get it. Best.

Comment: @Sonia please check the answer you think it was helpful to solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Status, do you have any other solution to created PDF files of any webpages of my website...

Comment: Have you tried the recipe I wrote to you? Where is the point? If you find another solution, please alert me because it will be a real finding.